# Visual Studio 2012 Add-In - How to share/publish/deploy it?

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2012, add-in, publish, vsix

I have been working on a Visual Studio solution template to be used internally and have been developing this in a Visual Studio 2012 Addin.

The addin is added to the tools menu of Visual Studio and all works fine.

The only question now is, how can I share this tool between my team?

I have added a VSIX project, which in turn references the Solution Template project (added as an asset) but will this alone do it?

I can't see how installing the VSIX I created is manually going to add my add-in to the Visual Studio Tools window.

Can anyone offer any advice as to how I can do this or is there some other way to deploy/publish a Visual Studio addin?

I have found a [tutorial](http://fascinatedwithsoftware.com/blog/post/2012/12/06/How-to-Create-a-Visual-Studio-2012-Project-Template-Part-4-VSIX-Deployment.aspx) which is similar, but I just want to use the VSIX to install my add-in to Visual Studio tools menu, rather than add it as a project template. I have looked around and there doesn't seem to be much information on how to deploy your addin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `addins` are soon to be deprecated with the next release of `Visual Studio`, although I have found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn246938%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) on how to convert an `addin` to a `VSPackage`.

And with a `VSPackage` I will be able to deploy using `VSIX`.

There are also some tutorials on `VSPackages` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138589.aspx).